# Why is this function continuous in the strip and analytic in it's interior? (Rubel's proof of Holder's Inequality)

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

Rubel's proof of Holder's Inequality is done in the following way:

Given the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, functions $f \in L^p$, $g \in L^q$ and conjugate exponents $p,q$, define

$\phi(z)= \frac{ \int_{\Omega} |f|^{p (1-z)} |g|^{qz} d\mu}{(\int_{\Omega} |f|^p d\mu)^{1-z} (\int_{\Omega} |g|^q d\mu)^{z}}$, where $z$ is a complex variable taking values in the strip $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 \leq \mathcal{R}(z) \leq 1\}$.

He claims this map $\phi$ is defined and continuous in the whole strip and analytic in it's interior. Why is that so?

The rest of the proof follows easily, since it's clear that $|\phi(\sigma+it)| \leq \phi(\sigma)$ for $0 \leq \sigma \leq 1$ and that $|\phi(it)|, |\phi(1+it)|$ are bounded by $1$ (so by the maximum modulus principle, $\phi(z) \leq 1$ in the whole strip and thus Holder's inequality holds (pun unintended) by taking $z=\frac{1}{q}$.

Answer (score 2):

Continuity follows from a dominated  convergence argument. Indeed, we take $(z_n)_n$ contained in the strip such that $z_n\to z$. We define 
$$h_n(x):=|f(x)|^{pz_n}|g(x)|^{q(1-z_n)}.$$
Then $h_n(x)\to h(x):=|f(x)|^{pz}|g(x)|^{q(1-z)}$. Let $a_n$ be the real part of $z_n$. We have 
$$|h_n(x)|=|f(x)|^{pa_n}|g(x)|^{q(1-a_n)},$$
and we can bound it by an integrable function using Young's inequality.

For analyticity, we can use [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem). It's indeed, sufficient to prove that the numerator is analytic. To this aim, we integrate since over a triangle contained in the strip $\{0\lt \Re z\lt 1\}$ and we use Fubini's theorem. (Morera's theorem requires the triangle is contained in the considered open set)

Comment: A wonderful suggestion, thank you. I'm now checking if Fubini's Theorem may indeed be applied (the conditions of the theorem and if the countour integral corresponds to the  integral w.r.t Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$). If so, this function is in fact analytic in the whole strip (not just the interior), isn't it? Also, could you please provide just some tips on how to show continuity by dominated convergence? Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added details. Is it clearer?

Comment: Let's see if I got it: by the D.C.T, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} |h_n| d\mu = \int_{\Omega} |h| d\mu$, so for every $\epsilon >0$, we get $\delta>0$ such that $|z-z_n|<\delta \implies |\int_{\Omega} |h| d\mu - \int_{\Omega} |h_n| d\mu | < \epsilon$, which means $\phi$ is continuous.